# Get memory leak when decode small jpg image in Android

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, imageview

I decode a small jpg image to bitmap in my app.

The image is only 40K.

I use these methods:

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String pathName,int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
    return bmp;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

and when the program goes to:

`Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);` 
I get GC_Concurrent in the LogCat,

why?

Comment: What language?  What platform?

Comment: Adroid (Java) in Eclipse

Comment: How do you determine there's a leak? `GC_CONCURRENT` messages are just normal status messages from the garbage collector and don't indicate a  leak of any sort. That is, what's is the problem, exactly?

Comment: know that GC_CONCURRENT is bad and can couse OUT OF MEMORY ERROR. see also in this lesson http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Answer (score 0):

`GC_CONCURRENT` per se is not bad. It's just a status message from the garbage collector doing its job. Image decoding involves memory allocations and it's normal to see garbage collector running.

Comment: Is GC_FOR_ALLOC is a different story? Is this warning is bad?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just another GC run triggered by a memory alloc.

Comment: But I see repeatedly this massage again and again, and the number of the Kilobyte is increasing till I get OOM error. Should I need to free Bitmaps that no longer visibles in listview?

Comment: You should ensure that nothing is holding references to objects you no longer need so GC can reclaim the memory.